# Could we use Material Icon with PrimeReact button

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, primereact

Currently I'm using Button from PrimeReact. They are using icon from PrimeIcons but the number of icon are limited and I'd like to use Material Icons with it.

```
<Button label='View/Edit Job' icon="pi pi-pencil" className="p-button-info" 
                  tooltip='View/Edit Job'
                  onClick={(e) => gotoJob(e, job.id)} style={{ width: '100%' }} />
```

If that is possible, please advice me.

Answer (score 1):

We were able to use material-icons and still have the same functionality.
However, you need to create a class for each icon you will use.
I think that is a little price to pay for this feature.

1. First install material icons `$ npm install material-design-icons`
2. We imported the CSS like so `@import 'material-design-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css';`
   *You can import it using the standard way with Link tag*

Create a class like so

```
.dms-mat-icon-email::before {
  content: "email" /* This is the icon name from material */;
}
```

You can now use the class like so

```
<Button
  icon="material-icons dms-mat-icon-email"
></Button>
```

We are using a wrapper component to dynamically pass the icon so we don't hardcode it

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Button } from "primereact/button";
import { Color } from "../theme/DMSTheme";
import classNames from "classnames";

interface IDMSButtonProps {
  label?: string;
  icon?: string;
  iconPos?: string;
  color?: Color;
  type:string;
}

const DMSButton: React.FunctionComponent<IDMSButtonProps> = (props) => {
  return (
    <Button
    type = {props.type}
      className={classNames({
        "dms-clr-text" : props.color && props.color === Color.Text,
        "p-button-text p-button-rounded": !props.label,
        "p-button-secondary" : props.color && props.color === Color.Secondary,
      })}
      iconPos={props.iconPos}
      label={props.label}
      icon={props.icon ? `material-icons dms-mat-icon-${props.icon}` : ""}
    ></Button>
  );
};

export default DMSButton;
```

If anyone has a better idea to simplify this, please comment!

Comment: We decided to switch to material-ui because we were spending most of our time tweaking their styles. While they have a great list of components, they are still not React.StrictMode compliant ex: (toast findDOMNode)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. But you will not be able to use it like you are using it currently. You can also use fontawesome icons. This is probably the best way yo use it.

```
<Button
    label="Hello"
    style={{
      display: "flex",
      justifyContent: "center",
      alignItems: "center",
      width: '100%'
    }}
    className="p-button-info" 
    tooltip='View/Edit Job'
    onClick={(e) => gotoJob(e, job.id)}
  >
    <AccountCircleIcon />
  </Button>
```